# Livefyre textarea scrolls to bottom on spacebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So, I'm running a small wordpress website which uses Livefyre comment system plugin. The website also uses Nicescroll, a plugin that makes your scroll bar 'cooler'. Now, whenever I try to create a space between letters inside the comment box, instead of a space, I get my window scrolled to the bottom of the page ( using Chrome ). I have tried various javascripts found on StackOverflow, without succes. I wanna mention that everytime I disable Nicescroll plugin, everything works perfectly.

What can I do to prevent my browser from scrolling to the bottom of the page when trying to use spacebar inside that specific textarea ? Also, I have a custom search box on my website, which apparently is not affected by nicescroll.

Comment: Well, you could just set the `spacebarenabled` option to false to disable scrolling via space bar at all (but users might expect that to work as it would with the normal scrollbar). If that’s not an option, then you either have to get into the event handling this plugin uses and figure out a way to not have keypress events from textareas bubble up to where it catches them, or modify its event handling to have it check whether the target element of the event was a textarea or not before it scrolls.

Comment: All I had to do is search for that plugin's jquery file, then search for the spacebarenabled:true inside it and modify it to false. Works like a charm, didn't think about that, thank you very much :D

Comment: OK, added that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just set the `spacebarenabled` option to false to disable scrolling via space bar at all (but users might expect that to work as it would with the normal scrollbar).

If that’s not an option, then you either have to get into the event handling this plugin uses and figure out a way to not have keypress events from textareas bubble up to where it catches them, or modify its event handling to have it check whether the target element of the event was a textarea or not before it scrolls.